# how to run dynamic sub services inside a service in symfony 3?

Tags: symfony

I have a main service that needs to run sub services depending on a parameter.

```
class MainService
{
    /**
     * $serviceIds = ['sub-a', 'sub-b', 'sub-c']
     */
    public function run(array $serviceIds)
    {
        foreach($serviceIds as $id) {
            $subservice = $this->getSubService('service.' . $id);
            $subservice->doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

MainService has to run just a few of subservices but there is up to 80 subservices registered in the service.yml.
I don't want to inject all of them into MainService because at runtime that means they will be loaded in the memory. I want only the usefull subservices to be loaded.
I know that if I inject the service container in the constructor of MainService I can access to those specific subservices but I read many times that injected the service container is a bad thing.
Do you know how I can handle this ?

Comment: The advice not to inject a container is just a guideline.  If you really don't know which services you need until run time then go ahead and inject it.  There are alternatives.  You might consider using a [service locator](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-service-locators). Or maybe some combination of factories or proxy's.  But don't over do it.  Injecting the container for what you described is probably fine.

Comment: @Cerad thank you for your reply, I will then stick to "the simplest the better" so I will use the service container.